# GDB an ELF File Under Win32

Tags: debugging, x86, gdb, nasm, elf

I wanted to study ELF relocation mechanism, so I assembled an x86 assembly program using NASM to produce an ELF file, but under Win32. Then I used mingw32's gdb to debug it. It loaded nicely and I could view the program using "list" command. However, I couldn't run it. I got the following messages:

```
Starting program: c:\Projects\NasmProjects\Test01\Hello.o
Error creating process c:\Projects\NasmProjects\Test01\Hello.o
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Wtf? How do you expect to be able to execute an unlinked object file?!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way around this?

No.

First, you have assembled a relocatable object file (of type `ET_REL`). There is no OS that will "run" such files -- OSes that do support executing ELF files, require a fully linked executable (of type `ET_EXEC` or `ET_DYN`).

Second, even if you manage to link an `ET_EXEC`, you *still* need your OS to know how to load and start executing such a file. Linux and Solaris kernels do know this, AIX and Windows kernels do *not*.